# 2D Arrays - sum diagonals, transpose, shift columns

Tags: c++

I recently turned in homework which I had thought I had done correct but my teacher marked me for things that I honestly thought were right.

The first question: Fill up the following code for computing the sum of values on the principal and minor diagonal in a square matrix A[7][7]. Assume the matrix is defined

```
int sum = 0; // he marked this wrong. Why is initializing to 0 wrong?
for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) { 
    for(int j = 0; j < 7; j++) { // also marked j < 7 wrong
        sum = sum + A[i][i] + A[i][7-1-i]
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Question 2: Transpose a square matrix A[50][50] i.e., the first row becomes the first column and vice-versa, the second row becomes the second column and so on. Assume the matrix is defined.

```
void transposeSquare(){
     for(int i=0;i<50;i++){
         for(int j=0;j<50;j++){ //marked j=0 wrong
             int temp = A[i][i];
             A[i][j] = A[j][i];
             A[j][i] = temp;
         }
     }
}
```

Why is j=0 in transposeSquare not right?
Why would sum be anything other than 0?
If i < 7 should j < 7 too if its a square matrix?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need a nested loop in the first question? In the second one, you only needed to iterate over half of the matrix: `for(int j=i+1;j<50;j++)`. Also, typo at `int temp = a[i][i];`. Should have been `int temp = a[i][j];`.

Comment: If you want to prove your teacher is wrong, why not just write a simple program showing your results are correct?

Comment: Your code seems to be missing a semicolon, is that a typo?

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong for couple of reasons.

1. By using a nested loop inside the outer loop, you are adding the numbers in the diagonals 7 times instead of just once.
2. When `i` is 3, the line

   ```
       sum = sum + A[i][i] + A[i][7-1-i]
   ```

   is equivalent to:

   ```
       sum = sum + A[3][3] + A[3][7-1-3]
   ```

   which is the same as:

   ```
       sum = sum + A[3][3] + A[3][3]
   ```

   Adding `A[3][3]` twice to the sum is not correct.

To fix the problems, use:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++){ 
   sum = sum + A[i][i] + A[i][7-1-i];
}
sum -= A[3][3]; // Remove the element that was added twice.
```

You can use `+=` to simplify the code a little bit.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++){ 
   sum += A[i][i] + A[i][7-1-i];
}
sum -= A[3][3]; // Remove the element that was added twice.
```

Comment: Maybe OP's teacher marked the initialization as wrong because they wanted it to be `int sum = -A[3][3];`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has small errors that's why your teacher has entitled your code as wrong.

For the first part,

```
int sum = 0;
int size = 7; 
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) { 
    sum += A[i][j] + A[i][sz-1-i]; // Error: Typo, it should be A[i][j] instead of A[i][i]
}
if(size%2 != 0)
    sum -= A[size/2][size/2];  // Missed Case: Subtract the middle element since its repeated only when the size of array is an odd number
return sum; // Return the sum at the end!
```

For second Part You don't need to iterate the whole two-D array. Because if you do so it will copy **upper triangle** into **lower triangle** instead of calculating the `Transpose`. So traverse any triangle (`Upper` or `Lower`).

Like I have traversed `Lower Triangle` in this code.

```
void transposeSquare(){
     for(int i=0;i<50;i++){
         for(int j=0; j<i ;j++){ // Fix 1: Loop j to i-1 
             int temp = A[i][j]; // Fix 2: Typo it should be A[i][j] instead of A[i][i]
             A[i][j] = A[j][i];
             A[j][i] = temp;
         }
     }
}
```

Checkout [**Triangular Matrix**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix)  for better explanation.

Comment: Pleaase note that the nested loop in the first snippet is also an error.

Comment: @Bob__ Thanks for Pointing out, Fixed!

Comment: Well, not really fixed ;) *"computing the sum of values on the principal and minor diagonal"*, you don't need the j loop at all.